# Steam Soundtracks for Games on Other Platforms

Tags: steam

I love the soundtrack to "Ori and the Blind Forest". It shows up in my account as purchased DLC when I look at the game in my library, but I don't see it under the Library>Music tab.*

My goal is to get the songs into my iTunes library, on my Mac PowerBook.

*: I don't see it in the Music tab whether I'm looking on my Windows gaming box OR my everyday-use Mac Powerbook.

Comment: Are you asking where they're stored? IIRC game soundtracks get downloaded to the game's directory under steamapps, although I'm not in a position to double-check right now.

Comment: You'll either need to move/copy the soundtrack out of this directory or configure iTunes to index music under the steamapps folder

Answer (score 2):

To get them into your steam library steam recommends using these two ways.

> https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5460-QTPM-9243
>   How do I add music to my Steam Music library?
>
> Using the Steam Client, go to Settings -> Music -> Set Up Music
>   Library. There you can add a new folder on your hard drive for Steam
>   to scan for MP3 files. Once scanned they will be ready for your
>   listening pleasure in your Steam Library.
>
> How do I add the soundtracks that I’ve bought on Steam?
>
> Soundtracks purchased on Steam will automatically be added to your
>   Steam Music library. However to include these files in your library,
>   you must have the base game installed on your hard drive. After you
>   have installed the game, Steam will automatically list its soundtrack
>   DLC in your library. You can also manually rescan your music library
>   to detect the new files, which is done via Settings -> Music -> Music
>   Library -> Scan Now.

For the actual soundtrack you can find it by doing the following

- Right Click  Ori and the Blind Forest in steam
- Select properties
- Select the tab "Local Files"
- Select "Browse Local Files..."

This will get you to the files, then it's a matter of finding where it downloads the soundtrack to. (Likely just a folder called "Soundtrack" or "OST")

Copy the files to wherever iTunes looks or have iTunes look at that folder.